# preg_match_all between dynamic tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I would like to grab each of my virtual hosts configurations and put them in an array using preg_match_all so I can extract information from each of them, for example...

```
$vHostConfig = '    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
        <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
           Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Require local
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName testing.com
        DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/testing.com
        <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/testing.com">
           Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Require local
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
        ServerName testing2.com
        DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/testing2.com
        <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/testing2.com">
           Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Require local
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
#    <VirtualHost *:80>
#        ServerName testing3.com
#        DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/testing3.com
#        <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/testing3.com">
#            Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
#            AllowOverride All
#            Require local
#        </Directory>
#    </VirtualHost>';

preg_match_all(<<what to put here>>, $vHostConfig, $vHostConfigMatches);
```

I would like to grab only the active configurations without a # at the beginning of the line meaning I should have three strings starting with `<VirtualHost` and finishing with `</VirtualHost>` in $vHostConfigMatches array. Is this possible?

Comment: while regex can indeed do this, it is worth noting that some sort of DOM parser will be much better and probably more efficient at doing this. [note 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) :: [note 2](https://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: I am not using this code in a browser, it is some custom code for managing my virtual hosts, it's so i can build custom features into my wamp menu

Comment: XHTML is still DOM structured, regardless of what you view it with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regular expression:

```
preg_match_all('/^\h*<VirtualHost.*?>.*?\R\h*<\/VirtualHost>/sm',
               $vHostConfig, $vHostConfigMatches);
```

Note that the array `$vHostConfigMatches` will have an additional nesting level, so just take the first one with `reset`:

```
print_r(reset($vHostConfigMatches));
```

Comment: An elegant answer, works perfectly. Much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could split it by line:
`$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $vhostConfig);`

Filter out all of the commented lines:
`$lines = array_filter($lines, function ($ele) { return substring($ele, 0) != "#"; });`

Put it back together:
`$vhostConfig = implode(PHP_EOL, $lines);`

Then use a regex to pull each virtual host (you may want something more precise:
`preg_match_all("@<VirtualHost [\d\.\*:]+>(.*?)</VirtualHost>@", $vhostConfig, $vhostConfigMatches);`

Untested, but should give you the idea. This also has the benefit of ignoring any commented line in a valid virtualhost

Comment: Love the approach you have taken, I had to edit your code a little 
`$lines = array_filter($lines, function ($ele) { return substr($ele, 0, 1) != "#"; });` unfortunately the preg_match_all doesn't work any suggestions?

Comment: This was the correct answer for only grabbing the active configurations but the regex pattern on trincot's answer is correct for splitting the active configurations into three array items

Answer (score 0):

Although the @trincot's answer works fine, it uses the `.*?` (lazy) quantifier which makes the regex engine highly active: this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MjGd9x/2) shows it takes 950 steps in this example.

So I think that, even if it seems a bit more complicated, this simple PHP snippet would run faster:

```
$result = array_reduce(
  explode(PHP_EOL, $str),
  function($result, $line) {
    if (trim($line[0]) <> '#') {
      if (strpos($line, '<VirtualHost') !== false) {
        $result[] = $line;
      } else {
        $result[count($result) - 1] .= $line;
      }
    }
    return $result;
  },
  []
);
```

At once, it merely:

- turns the original string into an array of lines
- drop any comment
- populates the needed result as expected